# Recursion Error - Maximum Recursion dept exceeded when ForeignKey('self') django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am getting an error in admin console while trying to open a model (employees in my case). This is occurring after adding a field which is a ForeignKey('self'). I guess it is conflicting with **str** method. If I comment out the method, there is no error, but all the objects in the model are appearing as 'employee object'. Here is what my error looks like https://ibb.co/jHt84Q

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import calendar  
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

class employees(models.Model):
    emp_id=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    emp_lname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    emp_loc = models.CharField(max_length = 100,null=True)
    manager_id=models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image',default='/profile_image/profile-icon.png')
    email = models.EmailField(default='app-engine@gmail.com', blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.emp_id) + '-' + self.emp_name + '-' + self.emp_loc+'-'+str(self.manager_id)


class leave(models.Model): 

    employee = models.ForeignKey(employees, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    status=models.CharField(max_length=1,default='P')
    ltype=models.CharField(max_length=2)
    message=models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def leave_length(self):
          return self.end_date - self.start_date+timedelta(days=1);

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + '/' + str(self.employee.emp_name) +'/'+str(self.start_date) +'/'+str(self.end_date) +'/'+str(self.status)+'/'+str(self.date_created)
```

Here is my traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/apply/employees/

Django Version: 1.11.3
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['apply.apps.ApplyConfig',
 'm_manage',
 'pending.apps.PendingConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\base.html, error at line 75
   maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object   65 :           <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
   66 :         {% endfor %}</ul>
   67 :         {% endif %}
   68 :     {% endblock messages %}
   69 : 
   70 :     <!-- Content -->
   71 :     <div id="content" class="{% block coltype %}colM{% endblock %}">
   72 :         {% block pretitle %}{% endblock %}
   73 :         {% block content_title %}{% if title %}<h1>{{ title }}</h1>{% endif %}{% endblock %}
   74 :         {% block content %}
   75 :          {% block object -tools %}{% endblock %}
   76 :         {{ content }}
   77 :         {% endblock %}
   78 :         {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
   79 :         <br class="clear" />
   80 :     </div>
   81 :     <!-- END Content -->
   82 : 
   83 :     {% block footer %}<div id="footer"></div>{% endblock %}
   84 : </div>
   85 : <!-- END Container -->


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\options.py" in get_field
  617.             return self.fields_map[field_name]

During handling of the above exception ('__str__'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\utils.py" in lookup_field
  283.         f = _get_non_gfk_field(opts, name)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\utils.py" in _get_non_gfk_field
  317.     field = opts.get_field(name)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\options.py" in get_field
  619.             raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))

During handling of the above exception (employees has no field named '__str__'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  178.             rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)

During handling of the above exception ('employees' object has no attribute '_manager_id_cache'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  84.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\template\library.py" in render
  225.         _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in result_list
  340.             'results': list(results(cl))}

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in results
  316.             yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in __init__
  307.         super(ResultList, self).__init__(*items)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in items_for_result
  218.             f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\utils.py" in lookup_field
  299.                 value = attr()

File "C:\Users\rhshanka\LMS\apply\models.py" in __str__
  15.         return str(self.emp_id) + '-' + self.emp_name + '-' + self.emp_loc+'-'+str(self.manager_id)


Exception Type: RecursionError at /admin/apply/employees/
Exception Value: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: One of your employees probably has himself as a manager.

Comment: I have checked my data and that case doesn't seem to appear. I have 10 employees and one of them is a manager whose manager_id = None

Comment: Then you will need to show more detail. Click the link on the error page which says "Switch to copy-and-paste view" and update the question with the resulting text.

Comment: Do you want to show the manager id (the int value) or are you actually trying to put the string representation of the manager in the method?

Comment: That site you uploaded the error image to doesn't allow zooming on mobile and it's illegible otherwise. All information relevent to the problem should be posted here directly, and as text whenever possible. What's the stack trace? That should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Done!

Comment: @IainShelvington   As it is just for displaying purpose, I have used string representation, so that i can concatenate with remaining attributes

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah I have edited my question. Thanks :)

Comment: @RaviShankar Hmm, not sure. Lots of bouncing between calls of `self.render`. If I were you, I'd fire up my debugger and watch it bounce around. May give you some more hints.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Hey, thanks for trying to help! The answer has solved the problem

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Hey, You were right..  Initially, I have set manager for all employees as some other object but later, when I commented out the str method, every employee's manager has become the first object of my table. I couldn't recognize that since the data is not being displayed, only 'employee object' was being displayed. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably simplify the `__str__` method to just show the ID and/or name rather than recursing into the manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
def __str__(self):
    self_str = '%s-%s-%s' % (self.emp_id, self.emp_name, self.emp_loc)
    if self.manager_id and self.manager_id.pk != self.pk:
        return '%s-%s' % (self_str, str(self.manager_id))
    return self_str
```

And you need to be sure your logic is correct, for many inherits it will be not readable.

Comment: glad to help you, this solution is rhe same the Daniel Roseman said to you

Comment: Yeah, I realized it later. Initially, I have set manager for all employees as some other object but later, when I commented out the __str__ method, every employee's manager has become the first object of my table. I couldn't recognize that since the data is not being displayed, only 'employee object' was being displayed.